# Can't set default value to EnumProperty when duplicating existing property

Tags: python

This is a follow up question to:

I'm trying to duplicate properties of an existing operator (the Alembic exporter). It works well I think, with the exception that I can't set a default value on EnumProps. I get a type error as soon as I enable the default value:

```
TypeError: EnumProperty(..., default=''): not found in enum members
```

Here's the code I have in the **init**.py. As soon as the default=prop.default is enabled the error is thrown. This works for String/Bool/Int/Float properties, but not Enums.

```
import bpy
    
def get_alembic_enums():
    props = []
    for prop in bpy.ops.wm.alembic_export.get_rna_type().properties:
        if prop.type == "ENUM":
            props.append(prop)
            
    return props

def dup_enum_prop(prop):
    '''
    Duplicate an EnumProp.
    '''    
    items = [(x.identifier, x.name, "") for x in prop.enum_items.values()]
    
    dup_prop = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name=prop.name,
        description=prop.description,
        items=items,
        # If this line is enabled an error occurs.
        default=prop.default
    )
    
    return dup_prop
    
    
class AlembicProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    __annotations__ = {x.identifier: dup_enum_prop(x) for x in get_alembic_enums()}
    
    
bpy.utils.register_class(AlembicProps)    
    
bpy.types.Scene.alembic_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=AlembicProps)
```

Comment: Hello ! Just as a shot in the dark, if the source enum property is dynamic (the items are gathered through a callback) the default attribute will not be available since dynamic enum props can't have a default value. You can try `prop.enum_items_static` https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.EnumProperty.html?highlight=enum_items_static#bpy.types.EnumProperty.enum_items_static

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems to give the same error unfortunately. Also, if i print prop.default it IS a valid value (meaning I have it in my items list), but I just can't set it for some reason.

Comment: Yup I didn't think it was the problem just wanted to give a heads up :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an enum with zero items and an empty `''` default value in the enums. It appears Blender doesn't like it when you set an empty default. So you can test for an empty default value and skip setting it:

```
import bpy
    
def get_alembic_enums():
    props = []
    for prop in bpy.ops.wm.alembic_export.get_rna_type().properties:
        if prop.type == "ENUM":
            props.append(prop)
            
    return props

def dup_enum_prop(prop):
    '''
    Duplicate an EnumProp.
    '''    
    items = [(x.identifier, x.name, "") for x in prop.enum_items.values()]
    
    # Test for empty default value
    if prop.default != '':
        dup_prop = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            name=prop.name,
            description=prop.description,
            items=items,
            default=prop.default
        )
    else:
        dup_prop = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            name=prop.name,
            description=prop.description,
            items=items,
        )
                
    return dup_prop
    
    
class AlembicProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    __annotations__ = {x.identifier: dup_enum_prop(x) for x in get_alembic_enums()}
    

bpy.utils.register_class(AlembicProps)    
    
bpy.types.Scene.alembic_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=AlembicProps)
```

It's not the most beautiful Python code, but it works ;-)

Comment: That does seem to work! Thanks